# Is it proper to use nested loops a lot in python?

Tags: python, cryptography

I have a project and I am trying to do a complex cryptographic method. Is it normal to use nested loops a lot? Or Did I miss something?

I intend to create a method which tries all strings to find password. For example, It should create each of these one by one: ('A','A') ('B', 'A') ('A', 'B') ('B', 'B') ('A', 'AA' ) ('A', 'AB') ('B', 'AA') ('B', 'AB') ('A', 'BA') ('B', 'BA') ('A', 'BB') ('B', 'BB') , (triple permutations), (quadruple permutations).. and it goes...

```
def rulefinder():
    global externalrul1
    global externalrul2
    rul2 = uniquestring1[0]
    rul1 = uniquestring1[0]
    for n in range (0,3):
     for m in range (0, len(uniquestring1)):
      for z in range(0, n+1):
        for k in range (0,3):
            for i in range(0, len(uniquestring1)):
                for o in range(0, k+1):
                    for y in range (0,  len(uniquestring1)):
                        rul2 = rul2[:-1] + uniquestring1[y]
                        for x in range (0, len(uniquestring1)):
                            rul1= rul1[:-1] + uniquestring1[x]
                            code=""
                            for cha in Genx1:
                                if cha==uniquestring1[0]:
                                    code +=codereplacer(rul1)
                                elif cha==uniquestring1[1]:
                                    code +=codereplacer(rul2)
                            print(code)
                            print(uniquestring1[0],rul1)
                            print(uniquestring1[1],rul2)
                            print(LastString)
                            if code == LastString:
                                axiom1=uniquestring1[0]
                                axiom2=uniquestring1[1]
                                externalrul1=rul1
                                externalrul2=rul2
                                print('rules are found')
                                print("First RULE:", uniquestring1[0], rul1)
                                print("Second RULE:", uniquestring1[1], rul2)
                                findsubgeneration(code, axiom1, rul1, axiom2, rul2)
                                return
                    rul1 = rul1[:o] + uniquestring1[i] + rul1[(o + 1):]
            rul1 += codereplacer(uniquestring1[i])
        rul2 = rul2[:z] + uniquestring1[m] + rul2[(z + 1):]
        rul1 =""
     rul2 += codereplacer(uniquestring1[m])
```

Comment: There are different "types" of loops: ignore loops with a constant bound on iterations, especially a low one. There are "regular" loops that grow (linearly) with "problem size": if you nest more than, say three of those, you won't *want* to wait for the solution for sizeable problem instances.Then, there are loops iterated more often: guess. Nesting more than two regular loops *should* get you thinking about your approach to a solution. Nesting more than three loops in any single place calls for reorganisation.

Comment: No time for a proper review but the itertools module offers many solutions which lead to code with fewer loops (and more efficient). It probably applies to your code but I haven't checked yet.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem by using permutations and itertools library. Now, I am using only 3 loops.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from your comment, using `itertools` did solve your problems.

Here are a few suggestions anyway (that you may want to take into account before submitting a new question with the updated code):

- instead of using global variables, you should add parameters to your functions.
- you could take this chance to add a proper documentation about what your function is supposed to do and what the parameters are.
- the indentations seem to be of various sizes. [PEP8, the Style Guide for Python code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommands using 4 spaces. It is probably worth reading the whole document.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to add document after the project is done and I will edit spaces as well.